# Bash script using `sudo` runs correctly from cli but not when clicked to run

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I am trying to get a simple bash script to run when I click on it.  It runs perfectly from the cli but starting `motion` with `sudo` fails to start.  I have that script setup with sudoers already for nopasswd, it starts up correctly and does not ask for password when run from cli.  It also closes everything correctly when ran from cli, but it is almost like the `sudo` lines get skipped when I just double click on the file and tell it to run.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_process() {
  [ "$1" = "" ]  && return 0
  [ `pgrep -n $1` ] && return 1 || return 0
}

check_process "motion"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  sudo /etc/init.d/motion start
  firefox http://localhost:8081/ > /dev/null &
else
  sudo /etc/init.d/motion stop
  killall firefox > /dev/null &
fi
```

Comment: try replacing 'sudo' with the 'gksu'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nautilus you have two options to run a script when you double click on it:

[image: Run a script from Nautilus]

#### 1. Run in Terminal

- Using this option, your script will run correctly (as you said).

#### 2. Run

- Using this option you have to use `pkexec` (or `gksu` if you have it installed) instead of `sudo`. That is because you can't run graphical commands which use `sudo` without to use an X terminal emulator, even if you set `sudo` to not ask for password.
- So, in this case, your script should look like:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  check_process() {
    [ "$1" = "" ]  && return 0
    [ `pgrep -n $1` ] && return 1 || return 0
  }

  check_process "motion"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    pkexec /etc/init.d/motion start
    firefox http://localhost:8081/ > /dev/null &
  else
    pkexec /etc/init.d/motion stop
    killall firefox > /dev/null &
  fi
  ```

Comment: switching to pkexec did work but still have to put in password each time.  Not horrible but I was hoping to make a launcher that I just clicked to turn motion on and off.  Is there a way to make it so I don't have to put in my password each time?

Comment: @user311472 You don't need *to put in password each time* if you follow the following answer: [How to configure pkexec to not ask for password?](http://askubuntu.com/a/388660/147044) :)