# Launch script with double click don't work

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to launch a bash with a double click on it.

I made a simple script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo Hello, who am I talking to?
read varname
echo "It's nice to meet you" $varname
```

and I also tried by putting #!/bin/bash but didn't change

I did

```
sudo chmod +x script_name 
dconf-editor
```

and set launch file on click in `dconf-editor`.

I also tried to add .sh extention to the file without success.

With all of this, the file is not running when i double click on it.
I'm using ubuntu 20.04, and I didn't find any helpfull post about this problem.
Maybe I didn't searched well or enough so feel free to send me

Additionnal intels :

- The script work well when I launch it from terminal,
- When I set "ask" in dconf-editor is ask me how I want to open it, but launch still don't work.
- Using the "ask" option, and then click on "run in terminal" make it work. But I want it to work without the ask window, to make it more user friendly.
- The post [Bash script using `sudo` runs correctly from cli but not when clicked to run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505720/bash-script-using-sudo-runs-correctly-from-cli-but-not-when-clicked-to-run) is not helping me since I don't have sudo commands inside my script.

expected behaviour:
A terminal is open saying "who am I talking about?"

Thanks a lot. And sry about my english level I'm not native.
Bouq

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some will say: "move to another desktop environment".

In the Gnome desktop environment, used by Ubuntu, the **ability to run any program by double-clicking on** it in the file manager is **deprecated**. It is indeed handy in some use cases. In other use cases, it can be confusing for users and for sure, it can be a security nightmare. Which is probably an important reason why it is deprecated.

It actually remains possible to set that up, however, it is not anymore set up by default.

- If you are a developer needing to run an application during development, open a terminal. Enter the name of the program once (use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for command completion. Then use arrow up to repeat the command.
- If you are an end user needing to run some application, then install it properly. Install or link the executable in your `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin` directory. Run it from the terminal just by typing the name, or create a launcher to it in `~/.local/share/applications`. Then, you can run it from the application overview, and even pin it to the dock for quick access.

Still, you could set up the ability to run files from the file manager by setting up a `.desktop` launcher that runs a file you provided as an argument. A `.desktop` launcher with the line `Exec=gnome-terminal -- %f` would open Gnome Terminal and (try to) run the file name provided, represented by the `%f`. If it is a script, you will see it running in the terminal. If it is a graphical application, Gnome terminal will briefly load, but disappear once the graphical application has started. A minimal `.desktop` launcher for this is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Generic application runner
Comment=Runs executable files
Exec=gnome-terminal -- %f
Type=Application
```

With the `.desktop` file installed in `~/.local/share/applications`, you can run any program by right-clicking and selecting "Open with...". You can associate files with a specific extension, e.g. `.sh` for scripts, to that launcher so it runs upon double click.

Alternatively, you will need to at least switch to a file manager still supporting the feature, or switch to another desktop environmemt like Mate or Xfce.

Comment: Thank you for this complete explanation, I better understand how all of this can work and why it's deprecated, thanks a lot. Actually I will choose the clean way, create an app.

Comment: Good, although I did some painful testing to have my .desktop launcher work ;) You need to log out then back in to have it appear in the "Open with" dialog.

Comment: Ok, thank you !

Comment: seems somewhat silly for gnome to deprecate that functionality. they still allow you to "Right click -> Run as program", so clearly the functionality is popular enough to warrant just running on double click automatically

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 22.04 I right mouse click then "run as program", this is not much more trouoble than doubleclick but I keep forgetting. When I doubleclick it opens the editor.

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to solve your problem.

### Desktop application

You can create a files with name and directory `~/.local/share/applications/abc.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Click-Script
Icon=</path/>
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c './script.sh;$SHELL'"
Categories=Application;
```

### Update preferences of Nautilus

Open Files (maybe it's called Nautilus) -> Perferences -> Behavior

Select `Ask what to do`

Comment: The second option is no longer available in 21.10 (with Gnome 40).

Comment: Didn't test the first option yet, but the second don't work, it is part of what I tried: `I set "ask" in dconf-editor` which also change this configuration in nautilus preferences also. It's the same setting. Btw, ty for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

These script are considered executables, so you can invoke only from a environment. (Unless you need to edit them).

i did these task with this method (on KDE plasma environment)

1. Create a .desktop file in your desktop with this content

> [Desktop Entry]
> Comment=link to my script
> Exec=/path/to/your/script
> GenericName=
> Icon=system-run
> Name=link to my script
> StartupNotify=true
> Terminal=true
> TerminalOptions=
> Type=Application

2. Save it and Perform a "double click" over for lastly show the magic !

**Note**
The option "Terminal=true". 
and you can invoke your task in a terminal window.
**Note 2**
obiously you can set "Always ask" in the "on open excecutable files" option in Dolphin ( Ctrl + shift + , )