# How come a bash script won't run without using xterm?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Strange.
I have a few scripts I use mostly after fresh install of Ubuntu.
They used to work, now they don't.
They are on an extra hdd, I thought may be permission issues, no.
I installed VPN and xterm, scripts for VPN use xterm, they work.
I tried adding xterm to scripts no longer working, now they work.
So, it's working that way but I don't know what happened.
I do have a fresh install. I wonder if just a bad install of Ubuntu.
I have never had a problem.

@steeldriver

Double clicking in file manager has allways worked before.

This does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update

sudo apt install -y xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
```

This works.

```
#!/bin/bash

xterm -e sudo apt update

sudo apt install -y xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
```

Comment: Is your "extra HDD" `mount`ed with the `noexec` option? `mount` will show you. Read `man mount`. What, precisely, do you mean by "now they don't"? How are you invoking the scripts?

Comment: @waltinator I have exec permision. what I mean is by they don't work is I try to run them and nothing happens.

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful: [Launch script with double click don't work](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379730/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver I guess I can accept option removed. I found a trick using xtern.