# How to suspend the machine from command line in LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, lxde, openbox

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 with Openbox 3.5.2.
There are one-liners for locking the screen: `dm-tool lock`
and for popping up the quit menu: `lxsession-default quit`

However, if I need to perform a suspend, I need to  pop up mentioned menu first,
then navigate to 'Suspend' option and press enter.

Can it be done with a single command?

Answer (score 5):

You can suspend from the terminal with:

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

In some cases, calling `pm-suspend` directly can cause problems with wi-fi drivers and other programs. Moreover, the man page for `pm-suspend` says that while it is ok to call it from the command line, it's normally intended to be called through your desktop power manager.

The man page adds that when called from the command line, `"it is not guarenteed that all of your programs in your desktop session keep working as expected."`

Most of the problems seem to be from services or modules not stopped or unloaded before the suspend. For a good discussion of this issue, along with ways to work around it, see [Suspend to Ram](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils#Standby.2Fsuspend_to_RAM) in the Arch wiki.

The Arch Wiki also suggests allowing a particular user to run `pm-suspend` without `sudo` through `visudo` to add the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
username  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

LXDE uses the `xfce4-power-manager`, which uses `pkexec` to call `pm-suspend`. `pkexec` allows execution of a program as another user, in this case `root`.

The authentication is handled by `polkit`. It would normally prompt for a password, but as I learned from [pkexec with no password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383747/how-to-configure-pkexec-to-not-ask-for-password) it is possible to suppress this through a file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions`.

There's a file there called `org.freedesktop.upower.policy` (`upower` is involved in calling `pm-suspend` but I left it out for simplicity).

This file contains the line `<allow_active>yes</allow-active>`, which is what allows the action to proceed without asking for a password.

Power-related actions are much more complicated than locking the screen or bringing up the menu. It may be better to use the suspend option in the power manager.

If your suspend function-key works, you might find that convenient. If it doesn't appear to work at first, check the settings in the power manager. In Lubuntu, the sleep button is not set to suspend by default.

You may also enjoy working through the issues at the Arch page in order to use `pm-suspend` directly. But be careful. I've used the command directly on several other laptops with no problem. On this particular laptop (Lenovo S10-3) it killed the wifi driver. I had to unplug the CMOS battery to get it working again.

Comment: ugh, I saw it before and forgot to mention. I quite don't like circumventing lxde/xsession mechanisms and running with elevated privileges, but perhaps clicking suspend button invokes `pm-suspend` eventually, but with some specific params. Is that correct?

Comment: Please see the edited answer :)

Comment: thanks for the detailed info. Any idea how to get the exact command that is issued then 'Suspend' is chosen from the menu other than analysing the code? btw: xfce4-power-manager isn't activated by default in Lubuntu.

Comment: I hope the answer has been helpful. The exact command is `pkexec pm-suspend`. It should not put up an authentication box. To my memory, on my recent Lubuntu install `xfce4-power-manager` was activated by default. And it's on the list of [installed tools and preferences](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Setup#System_Tools) in the Lubuntu docs.

Comment: `pm-suspend` doesn't seem to exist on Lubuntu Bionic Beaver.

Answer (score 2):

Sure,

you can try this:

```
echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

maybe you have to be sudo to run it.

Comment: Yep, `echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state`, to write to that file as root, works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through DBus no need for `sudo` or higher privileges. You may create an alias or script for it.

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement \
 /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement \
 org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Suspend
```

Better to explore for all available option using  `d-feet`.

1. Install d-feet

   ```
   sudo apt-get install d-feet
   ```
2. Follow

   D-Feet → Session Tab 
   → `org.freedesktop.PowerManagement` 
   → `/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement` 
   → `org.freedesktop.PowerManagemenl`

   D-Feet → System or Session tab 
   → `<dbus-name>` 
   → `<object-path>` 
   →  `<interface>`: list of methods, properties & signals

**References:**

- [`man dbus-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dbus-send.1.html)
- `/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.xml`

  `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` for session bus
  `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/` for system bus

  `/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/` interfaces from both

  Accessing system bus service *most* need root privileges or policy edit `polkit`. See [chaskes](https://askubuntu.com/users/117123/chaskes) answer.