# How to see what pkaction a software uses

Tags: permissions, password, gksu, policykit, visudo

So, I have one software that always asks for password when starting. And I want to run this software without this `gksu` password prompt popping up everytime.

The first thing I tried was adding its path to sudoers. However, that didn't work. Later I found out there's a thing called policykit, and if some program wants to use some of policykit actions, it will always prompts user for password (sudoers have no effect on it).

I followed a guide in [How do I prevent PolicyKit from asking for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98006/how-do-i-prevent-policykit-from-asking-for-a-password), but it still doesn't work, so I think I might have added wrong action.

Question: How I can see what `pkaction` does my program use so I can enter it in my .pkla file?

Comment: Which software in particular do you want to run like this? What *exactly* did you try to achieve that and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

Ask Ubuntu has this answer ([How to configure pkexec to not ask for password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383747/how-to-configure-pkexec-to-not-ask-for-password)) that is closer to what you need than the link you found earlier.

As a quick example to finding the application, I'll illustrate using my own script. I wanted to replace `gksu` which is being deprecated with `pkexec` so I wrote a wrapper script called **gsu**.

I invoke **gsu** from the command line with:

[image: gsu pkexec]

Notice the **Details** drop down arrow. Click it and this is revealed:

[image: gsu pkexec details]

In my example the **pkla** is controlled by ***org.gnome.gedit***. I'll use that in the next example, which you would replace with your own:

[image: gsu pexec authorities]

If you want to run without password prompt you would set the following:

```
  <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
  <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

On a personal note I don't like repeatedly entering the password myself but will not change `gedit` to never ask for password when changing root files using `pkexec`. However I would like it to not repeatedly ask for password when running it many times in given session. You can do this with `sudo` and you can extend the period from 10 minutes to 120 minutes as I have done on my system. I would like similar functionality for policy kits.

Comment: There are cases where no prompt is made:  http://askubuntu.com/a/884708/158442

Comment: @muru You wrote an excellent answer there and only got one upvote while **Byte Commander** got 16 upvotes for the question. Deviation from normal Q&A voting. +1 for the answer there but would you like me to put your link into my answer too?

Comment: no, but I'd like to know how to find the action when there is no prompt. In that case, I knew  beforehand the actions used by shutdown, restart, etc., but they have changed before and may change again.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem counter-intuitive to bypass the security of a [policykit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) authorization. In the absence of any further details my best advice is **don't do it.**

Be that as it may,

A mechanism needs to declare a set of actions in order to use polkit. Actions correspond to operations that clients can request the mechanism to carry out and are defined in files that the mechanism installs into the /usr/share/polkit-1/actions directory.

`pkaction --verbose`

will produce detailed output regarding all policykit actions. This will be useful when reviewing local config files. You can redirect this output to a text file for later review in the usual way `>later.review.txt`

These config files are found in the directories listed when you issue the command `sudo ls /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/`

```
10-vendor.d  20-org.d  30-site.d  50-local.d  90-mandatory.d
```

dig around and find the .pkla file that corresponds to ***your unidentified software***. Absent any useful information I'll pretend it's the Unity Greeter for example. We can review the lines that begin with `Action=` with the command  `sudo grep "Action=" /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/unity-greeter.pkla` Which results in

```
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax;
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.use-user-connections
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
```

For further information the latest polkit reference manual can be found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/) and related information on systemd can be found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)

As @muru points out there's also a related Q&A [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789058/how-to-make-sbin-shutdown-sbin-reboot-etc-require-sudo-again-in-16-04/884708#884708)

Sources:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html

[How do I prevent PolicyKit from asking for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98006/how-do-i-prevent-policykit-from-asking-for-a-password)

Comment: Of course, this needn't always be about bypassing security, but could be the other way around: http://askubuntu.com/a/884708/158442 and best I can tell, systemd doesn't have a file in `10-vendor.d`

Comment: @muru, good point regarding the bypass of security. I suppose the OP's statement regarding wanting to bypass the password led me to the conclusion that that was the intent. The `10-vendor.d` is an example from one of my systems running the Unity desktop.