# Trying to run a script on system startup

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I have been trying to get my script run right after I reboot. I have tried editing the `rc.local` file without success. After that I tried to add an entry to Startup Applications with the path to my script `/home/user/Scripts/myScript.sh`.

Then my system rebooted running the wanted script. The problem obviously isn't with execution privileges (which I've added with `chmod` command) but with denied access, because the command was not run with root privileges. Since `gksu` and `gksudo` is no longer supported, I was wondering how could I work around this problem.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, 64-bit

I also now found, that running `rc.local` does run the script, however it does not run on startup

Permissions of the script:

```
user@d4tor:~$ ll /home/user/Scripts/myScript.sh
-rwx--x--x 1 user user 129 July  3 16:50 /home/user/Scripts/myScript.sh*
```

Permissions of `rc.local`:

```
user@d4tor:/etc$ ls -l rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 328 July  5 17:45 rc.local
```

Comment: adding it to your root user's [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) might do the trick.

Comment: How do you know startup applications ran the script? Can you update your question with the output from `ll /home/user/Scripts/myScript.sh` and `cat /home/user/Scripts/myScript.sh`?

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` will absolutely certainly be run as root upon system startup, if it exists and it is executable. You may be making a confusion between system startup and the start of a graphical session for a user. (A system can run happily without having any user loggen in in a graphical session.) They are not the same thing, and do not run the same scripts. There is very little reason to run a script as root in a user's graphical session; there is never any good reason to run a GUI program as root.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am certain of it because my script launches a gnome-terminal and excecutes commands there. As I put the script path into rc.local, nothing happened but after I added it into startup applications it ran the terminal but asking me for permissions. The script is also excecutable because I have checked the permissions of rc.local and the script I use. The rc.local also runs just fine opening a terminal when I manually run rc.local.

Comment: I don't know why you would want/need to run a gui program at startup. However if you really want to, gui programs now need to use `pkexec` to run as root. You can read the first answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/383747/how-to-configure-pkexec-to-not-ask-for-password to see how to let a program use pkexec without password, and then your script should work.

Answer (score 0):

### Make script readable

Your script is only readable by the owner. The first step (just to be safe) would to make it readable by everyone:

```
chmod a+r /home/user/Scripts/myScript.sh
```

If that doesn't solve your issues, please update your question with the actual contents of your script.

Comment: Ill try that. just to be safe ill add a+rwx to the script